# Big Headache: CodeIgniter or custom made framework, what's your thoughts?

Tags: php, codeigniter

If you'd like to develop a WebApp which you know that is going to scale and become bigger and bigger over time, would you use CodeIgniter or your custom made framework?

What's your arguments for using an open source framework and what's your arguments against it.

Here are my thoughts:
**CodeIgniter Pros**

- Great documentation -> Easier to work in a team.
- All the development time is invested in the business logic.
- Not reinventing the wheel

**CodeIgniter Cons**

- Not sure how scalable it is if I'll want to grow
- MIT License - not sure what it means, but if I'll want to sell my app on per license basis, I'm not sure I'll be able to do that.

**Custom coded Framkework Pros**

- Scalable. I can decide how it will grow.
- I own the code
- Flexcible design.

**Custom coded Framework Cons**

- Need to document it, so others will be able to collaborate.
- Need to invest time to maintain the framework
- Unexpected errors/bugs

What's your take on that? My brain tells me to go with CodeIgniter, my heart tells me to build my own framework.

Comment: There are more frameworks out there than just CodeIgniter, why not see which one suits your requirements best.

Comment: Yii or zend. But i don't know about zends license. Yii is definitely more suitable than codeigniter. But then again, if you are targeting plugin developer, yiis learning curve is steep. That'l put restriction in boundary of your developers.

Comment: I like the simplicity of CodeIgniter :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use something that already exists.

**Why CI**

Why limit your choice to one framework - it makes the choice a near [straw man argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man)  your heart doesn't tell you to write your own framework - your ego does. If you eliminate the huge number of other frameworks that exist before starting - you're already on a path to .. lots of work.

And CI is quite a poor one-choice.

Php is, at the time of writing, at 5.4.0 - if you're in a position to choose what framework to use for a new project - seriously consider using a framework that uses 5.3+ features - or is already on the road to do so. Don't choose a framework which has a legacy code base full of php4 style code.

**CI Cons**

> Not sure how scalable it is if I'll want to grow

Most likely (and I don't use or like code igniter) more scalable than a random custom framework.

> MIT License

There are practically no restrictions on how to use MIT licensed software. Read MIT as "don't delete or modify the license blocks in the framework files" that's about it.

**Custom coded Framework Pros**

> Scalable. I can decide how it will grow.

Are you sure you know what scalable means :)

> I own the code

True in almost all cases - and definitely true if you use an MIT licensed framework.

> Flexible design

That's not likely to be a benefit in the long run. For example you achieve explosive success and need to bring on a team of developers. You will have to train each of them in how to use the custom framework on which the app is built. That's instead of simply pointing them at a few tutorials to get over the initial learning curve of using <insert name of chosen framework here>.

**Custom coded Framework Cons**

> Need to document it, so others will be able to collaborate.

Realistically, unless you build a framework capable of competing with the existing frameworks that's not going to happen (even with good documentation).

> Need to invest time to maintain the framework

Don't underestimate how much time that'll take.

> Unexpected errors/bugs

You'll spend a lot of time here.

**In summary**

1. A php framework is a lot of work and a lot to maintain. and by a lot - I mean **a lot**.
2. Time you spend on framework-level code is time you won't spend on your own application features.
3. Using a php framework means you can benefit from the experience of (hopefully) more experienced developers. Without the high cost of learning the hard way why x doesn't work, or why y leaves your application wide open to some security problem.
4. Whenever something isn't working correctly you won't know for sure if it's in your app code or your framework code (that's true no matter what, but you'll want the confidence to know that the framework "just works" and that your problems are in your app code)
5. Every time you blink there's a new php framework, and they all suck in some way - do you want to be one of those?

I'd really like to add the existence of unit tests so you can know that your application will work - but code igniter doesn't have that, so if you're rigid on your two choices I guess you're on your own with that either way.

Answer (score 7):

Here are few code fragments from CodeIgniter 2.1.0 .. look at them and then tell me tht this is how php code should look like in 2012:

- from [system/core/CodeIgniter.php](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/CodeIgniter.php)

  ```
  if (function_exists("set_time_limit") == TRUE AND @ini_get("safe_mode") == 0)
  {
      @set_time_limit(300);
  }
  // -- snip --
  $CFG =& load_class('Config', 'core');
  // -- snip --
  $UNI =& load_class('Utf8', 'core');
  // -- snip --
  function &get_instance()
  {
      return CI_Controller::get_instance();
  }
  // -- snip --
  ```
- from [system/database/DB.php](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/database/DB.php)

  ```
  if ( ! isset($active_record) OR $active_record == TRUE)
  {
      require_once(BASEPATH.'database/DB_active_rec.php');

      if ( ! class_exists('CI_DB'))
      {
          eval('class CI_DB extends CI_DB_active_record { }');
      }
  }
  else
  {
      if ( ! class_exists('CI_DB'))
      {
          eval('class CI_DB extends CI_DB_driver { }');
      }
  }
  ```
- from [`index.php`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/index.php)

  ```
  if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
  {
       switch (ENVIRONMENT)
       {
            case 'development':
                 error_reporting(E_ALL);
            break;
            case 'testing':
            case 'production':
                 error_reporting(0);
            break;
            default:
                 exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
       }
  }
  ```

  Until PHP 5.4 the `E_ALL` did not include `E_STRICT`, which means that "development environment" is hiding some errors. An in the production environment the hie all errors, instead of `ini_set('display_errors', false);`, which would be the reasonable choice.

This should illustrate the *superior* code quality of CodeIgniter ...

How about you at first choose a framework which make sense, and then start throwing around fancy words like "scalable" and "flexibility".

Comment: @AD7six , the `eval()` part is just funny. A lot more serious is that they are still using the `$foo = & new Bar;` syntax. It's just hidden behind `$foo =& load_class('Bar', 'core');` now. Most of CI codebase is still based on code that was made for php4. And the `$CI =& get_instance();` is just adorable .. they should just cut the act and replace it with `global $CI;` .. would make it less confusing.

Comment: I agree that the bootstrapping process is not the best practice, however in my opinion the API that CI provides is beautiful OOP programming. But I guess it's subjective...

Comment: @tounano .. calling static functions is not OOP

Comment: @tereško They call those functions only in the bootstrap process to init the core components.

As a user, coding inside the framework is beautiful OOP.

Comment: you must have a different definition or words "beautiful" and "OOP"

Answer (score 4):

I would say go with something that is already written. I dont really know CodeIgniter so I cannot comment on it scalability, but if after some investigation the scalability is not as you want it then take a look at some of the other PHP frameworks that exist out there.
There is bound to be one that you can base your app on.

Comment: Thanks,
What's your favorite framework?

Comment: I love http://flourishlib.com/ but that is not actually a framework at least not in the same sense of the word as CodeIgniter. One of my colleagues is using http://symfony.com/ for example. One thing to evaluate would also be the ZendFramework. What you really need to do is test a few and pick the one that gives you the flexibility you want and is scalable. And by test i mean to take at least a day with each and really evaluate it if it can do what you expect.

Comment: I would also recommend Zend Framework. I also like [yiiframework.com](http://www.yiiframework.com). It is a lot easier to learn, especially if you have prior framework experience.

Comment: Here is a list that you can use as a starting point for selecting candidates: http://matrix.include-once.org/framework/simple

Comment: @KillerX Thanks for introducing me to Flourish. This thing is amazing!!!

Comment: @Sthe YII is worst of the worst in terms of code quality

Answer (score 2):

If you are ready to invest time in building your own framework, then, like most people identified above, you will end up spending a lot of time fixing errors / bugs and most of all maintaining it.

In my 6 years of experience, I can tell you this, code maintenance is *not* a joke. It takes a lot of thought, careful planning and effort. And when you talk about a framework, it becomes inevitable to write unit tests.

You can invest less than half of that time in learning a new PHP framework that uses 5.3+ or is going there soon. My suggestions would be:

1. Use CodeIgniter if you want to be stuck with legacy code and primitive programming style. But you can definitely build a custom frameowrk on top of CodeIgniter and enhance it easily without changing the core. You *will* get performance out of CodeIgniter, but you will loose a lot of other goodies, biggest of all are the new features offered by PHP 5.3+ especially 5.4.
2. Use CakePHP 2.0 if you like to use a framework that uses a true MVC pattern and enforces best practices (and eventually makes you a better, disciplined coder) and will give good performance too. Has a large community from which you will find a lot of plugins / components already coded for the common problems. Hence accelerating development.
3. Use Lithium if you truly want to use the power of PHP 5.3+ with great performance, flexibility and a smaller footprint. This framework will offer a steeper learning curve if you are relatively new to programming. It will enforce best practices and introduce you to a new and better way of thinking.

There are other great PHP frameworks out there. However, since I have spent time in the ones mentioned above, so I am letting you know my birds eye opinion of these.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

No to both.
Don't write you own framework. It's **a lot** of work and at the latest when it comes to security it will most probably fail.

On the other hand, don't use CodeIgniter, because you cannot use any modern design pattern there. See this article: [Why CodeIgniter is dead](http://heybigname.com/2012/05/06/why-codeigniter-is-dead/)

I recommend you to use another framework - maybe [zend](http://framework.zend.com/). Or you'll do the step and use even [JSF](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/) or [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/).

Answer (score 0):

> All the development time is invested in the business logic.

You forgot learning curve here.
All the development time invested in the business logic, yes.
But before you can start, you have to learn whole brand new language, which is not the PHP you know, but completely different one. And many times *bigger.*

> Scalable. I can decide how it will grow.

Only if you are seasoned enough to know all the possible issues.
We all learning constantly, and with knowledge I have now I'd take some other decisions a year ago.

To me, the main disadvantage of all the "official" frameworks - they are bloated. Made with compatibility in mind, they support thousands negligible issues, bloating the code.
If you want to amend some part of the code - you are in trouble. The code is BIG and you have no idea of it. And you need ages to learn it.

Main advantage of the official frameworks to me is not even docs but rather *google.* A community. A knowledge base called Internet. Working with  a domestic framework sometimes I feel a "google-sick", a sort of physical abstinence when I want to google for some problem but I know I'll find nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I know CI pretty well, and it's easiest learning curve I ever had.

What's beautiful about CI (I read most of it's source code) is that it's pretty modular and lightweight.

It's core module and one of the single classes that is initiated is the loader class, which loads libraries on demand in a lazy load approach.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how ambitious you are and how much time you have to put into it. I developed a framework for my company that works great, and we've built a CMS on top of it with something like 30 installations floating around out there with very few problems. (Our other developers use it without issue, and because they can ask me when they run into problems, it often makes debugging easier because I know it like the back of my hand.)

But don't underestimate the amount of time that goes into doing it and maintaining it. No matter how good you think your ideas are when you start, you will realize through using it that there are always improvements you can make. A plethora of them. Ultimately, that's why I built something custom, though. Because as I run into new problems, I can develop novel solutions that ultimately improve the framework's flexibility in a way that I can dictate.

If you decide to go with a third-party option, though (which is honestly generally the best idea), don't use Code Igniter. It was developed for PHP 4 and is immensely lacking in features and general OOP style.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to develop a WebApp, I suggest you :  [**bonfire**](http://cibonfire.com/) which I find usefull. It is based on CodeIgniter framework